# How install VTK 9.0.1 on QT 6.1.0 Windows 10. Error (invalid numeric argument "/ Wno-error = invalid-offsetof")

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, visual-studio-2019, vtk

I had a problem while installing VTK version 9.0.1 on QT version 6.1.0. In the VTK files I changed from QT 5 to QT 6. In CMake, the rebuild was successful, but when I try to compile it gives an error that **invalid numeric argument "/ Wno-error = invalid-offsetof"** in the following projects: GUISupportQt, GUISupportQtSQL, ViewsQt.

Here is the output of the CMake build:
[image: Here is the output of the CMake build]

Comment: I don't see any output from CMake. Did you tell VTK to use QT6 and direct it to the `lib/cmake/Qt6` folder? Did you remove build dir and/or clean the cache? I use the latest development of VTK together with Qt6 - only problem I had was I needed to manually install LZ4

Comment: Hello, yes, I specified the path to Qt6 in the VTK parameters and manually changed everything from Qt5 to Qt6. And where to clear the cache?

Comment: Simplest solution is to remove the output directory, which will also remove any cached values. The error you are reporting seems like a GNU or Clang compiler argument that is passed to Visual Studio. Figure out to which library it is set and search the CMakeLists.txt files for where it is set. Could be a bug in VTK. I use the latest development branch from mid May and it is working fine